# How do I access a router's web interface which is connected to another router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My main router is the ADSL router. I have an Ethernet cable going from one of the LAN ports of the ADSL router to the WAN port of WiFi router. I've set both routers to DHCP. IP addresses on the ADSL router go from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254 and from 192.168.6.2 to 192.168.254 on the the WiFi router. I can access the web interface of the ADSL router when connected to the ADSL router using the IP 192.168.1.1. Similarly, I can access the web interface of the WiFi router when connected to the WiFi router using the IP 192.168.6.1. What I want to know is how to access the web interface of the WiFi router when I'm connected to the ADSL router. The WiFi router is allocated IP 192.168.1.100. I can ping it but I cannot get access to it's web interface through a browser. What can I do ?

PS: Sorry for being overly verbose.

Comment: can you share model numbers for the routers? there may be settings for the web interface in the wifi router that control what IPs can access it - or there may be a firewall rule in either router that's blocking traffic between the two subnets (x.x.1.x and x.x.6.x)

Comment: The ADSL router is Huawei HG531s V1. The WiFi router is Tenda W316R.

Answer (score 0):

In a default configuration you should **not** be able to access the configuration page of a router through its WAN port. That is the port meant to be connected to the untrusted Internet.

That said, some routers have a configuration option to allow "remote management" (or something similarly named). If your Wi-Fi router has this option you can enable it to accomplish what you're asking for.

If this option is not available to you, you can access the Wi-Fi router's configuration page using one of these alternatives:

- Remote into a device on the Wi-Fi network (e.g. via Remote Desktop), then access the configuration page from that device.
- Connect the Wi-Fi router to your ADSL router via a LAN port instead of the WAN port. This would require configuring the Wi-Fi network to use the same IP subnet as used by the ADSL router. In your case you would also need to disable DHCP on one of the routers.